# If $a,b\in Z(G)$, $ord(a) = 24$, $ ord(b) = 21 $, $ ord(c) = 5$ prove that some element has order $210$

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

> Let$\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}\DeclareMathOperator\lcm{lcm}$ $G$ be a group and $Z= Z(G)$ denote its center. Suppose $a,b\in Z$ and $c\in G$ such that $\ord(a) = 24$, $\ord(b)=21$, $\ord(c)=5$. Prove that there exists an element in $G$ with order $210$.

**What I tried**

I know that $a,b,c$ are abelian with each other.

so if $\gcd(a,b,c) = n$ then

$(abc)^n = a^nb^nc^n$

I tried playing a lot with the $\lcm$ and $n$ but didn't get anywhere.

Any hint or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(a^{12}bc)^{210}=1$. Now what else do we need to make a conclusion here?

Comment: thanks! I think that I need to show that it dosen't become 1 for any order less then 210? so I show that $lcm(2,5,21) = (2*5*21)/gcd(2,5,21) = 1$ ? Is that enough?